# Calling a function that has the same name as an argument to the local function

Tags: python

Suppose I'm writing a module which contains a function called `normalize()`, and another function `double()`, which also has a parameter named `normalize`. From inside of `double()`, I want it to call `normalize()`, but this is a problem because the parameter has the same name as the function.

```py
def normalize(x):
    return x * 100

def double(n, normalize = True):
    n = n * 2
    if (normalize):
        n = normalize(n)
    return n
```

This doesn't work, because the call to `normalize(n)` is trying to use the local variable `normalize`, instead of the outer function with the same name.

I don't want to rename the `normalize` function or the `normalize` parameter, because both of those names are meaningful. How can I make this work?

One possibility that I've considered is to make a copy of the `normalize` function, and also use `__all__` so that the copy isn't exported.

```py
__all__ = ['normalize', 'double']

def normalize(x):
    return x * 100

normalize_copy = normalize

def double(n, normalize = True):
    n = n * 2
    if (normalize):
        n = normalize_copy(n)
    return n
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe `normalize_function = globals()['normalize']`?

Comment: why not change variable name to `should_normalize` as that is even more meaningful

Comment: Honestly you are overthinking it. You have a name clash, so two obvious solutions are (1) use namespaces (i.e. import a module that contains the function or wrap it in a class) or (2) rename one of them (+1 for @JoranBeasley's `should_normalize` suggestion).

Comment: @Selcuk or even, using a `types.SimpleNamespace`.

Comment: See [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): `Simple is better than complex`, `[...] practicality beats purity`, and `Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!`

Comment: "I don't want to rename the normalize function or the normalize parameter, because both of those names are meaningful." 

Well, clearly they're not. You can't decide what they mean! Meaning only one thing is a rather big part of being meaningful.

Answer (score 4):

Here's kind of a goofy workaround, but you could do this; it rebinds the `normalize()` function into a new name in the parameter list.

```
def double(n, norm_func=normalize, normalize=True):
    n = n * 2
    if normalize:
        n = norm_func(n)
    return n
```

Comment: This is really cool as it's completely encapsulated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to strongly recommend you change your argument name to `should_normalize` since this is even more meaningful than `normalize` in this context.

If that is not a good solution for you for whatever reason then I will second the suggestion from the comments to use namespace encapsulation:

```
import types

def normalize(x):
    return x * 100

NS = types.SimpleNamespace(normalize=normalize)

def double(n,normalize):
    n = n * 2
    if normalize:
        n = NS.normalize(n)
    return n
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it if you want to change the API a bit, like below. The argument `normalize` now carries a function value rather than a boolean value.

```
def normalize(x):
    return x * 100

def double(n, normalize = None):
    n = n * 2
    if (normalize):
        n = normalize(n)
    return n

print(double(10, normalize))
```

@tdelaney, We can invert the `normalize` argument like below if the default action should always be `normalizing`.

```
def normalize(x):
    return x * 100

def double(n, normalize = normalize):
    n = n * 2
    if (normalize):
        n = normalize(n)
    return n

print(double(10))
```

Comment: The downside is that users of the API will have to know to call with the normalize function.

Answer (score 1):

To me, your second solution is the simplest, but you don't actually need to use `__all__`, just an underscore.

```
_normalize = normalize  # For use in "double()", which has a param "normalize"

def double(n, normalize=True):
    n = n * 2
    if normalize:
        n = _normalize(n)
    return n
```

I'd also add a comment to indicate why that line is there.

Comment: I like it -- it's simple and does the job.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to change the name of the parameter. You could ask the global scope for the object directly

```
def normalize(x):
    return x * 100

def double(n, normalize = True):
    n = n * 2
    if (normalize):
        n = globals()["normalize"](n)
    return n
```

But then people will wonder why you didn't just change the name of the parameter.